# How to run a changeset only on production environment?

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I have one changeset in my changelog file in my spring boot application. I want to run this changeset only on prod env not on dev env. Is there any way other than using context in liquibase for running chageset in specific env only (like any kind of precondition logic)? I have changeset like this-

```
<changeSet id="EVENT_ARCHIVE" author="jk">
                 <sql>some query</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Does it help -> https://www.liquibase.org/blog/contexts-vs-labels

Comment: is there any precondition logic?

Comment: Have a look at answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645232/how-to-divide-liquibase-package-structure-for-dev-and-prod-environment-in-spring)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :)

Comment: why you don't want to use context? It's used exactly for this usecase. If you want you can create some sql precondition that will check something in DB but that's maybe more complicated.